# why bash read doesn't remove excess trailing IFS characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, read

This command:

```
read -d 'z' a < <(printf 'a\n\n\n'); printf "$a"
```

outputs:

`a`

bash's `read` removes excess trailing newlines which is expected.

and by changing the `IFS` to null character:

`IFS= read -d 'z' a < <(printf 'a\n\n\n'); printf "$a"`

it outputs:

```
a 
(blank line)
(blank line)
```

`read` no longer removes the excess trailing newlines since `IFS` no longer includes newline character ...

but now if we do the same but with `m` instead of newlines:

```
IFS=m read -d 'z' a < <(printf 'ammm'); printf "$a"
```

one would think the output would be:

`a`

but the actual output is:

```
ammm
```

i.e. now `read` doesn't remove the excess trailing `IFS` characters (in this case `m` character).

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field splitting specifically ignores leading and trailing IFS whitespace. From the [GNU Bash manual, 3.5.7 Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting):

> If `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`,
>   the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at
>   the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are
>   ignored, and any sequence of `IFS` characters not at the beginning or
>   end serves to delimit words. If `IFS` has a value other than the
>   default, then sequences of the whitespace characters `space`, `tab`,
>   and `newline` are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as
>   long as the whitespace character is in the value of IFS (an IFS
>   whitespace character).

The courtesy isn't extended to non-whitespace characters. You can check this using other instances of field splitting:

```
bash-5.0$ printf "|%s|\n" $(printf '\n\na\nb\n\n')
|a|
|b|
bash-5.0$ IFS=' '; printf "|%s|\n" $(printf '  a b  ')
|a|
|b|
bash-5.0$ IFS=z; printf "|%s|\n" $(printf 'zzazbzz')
||
||
|a|
|b|
||
```

Answer (score 1):

by default read strips leading/training white space and newlines. If you add IFS then the default value is there so read won't strip them.

In your example

```
IFS=m read -d 'z' a < <(printf 'ammm'); printf "$a"
```

You gave `IFS` a value so now you have 2 fields/column but you only gave  one variable to read which is a, If you gave another variable which will hold the second feld

```
IFS=m read -d 'z' a b < <(printf 'ammm'); printf '%s %s' "$b" "$a"

mmm a
```

I'm not good on the details so someone can explain more but that's how I understood it.